# Cloth sim makes hole in my cloth

Tags: baking, cloth-simulation

When I bake my cloth sim so the cloth will fall on the chair,instead of covering it like it is supposed to,the back of the chair rips a hole in the cloth. How do I stop this?
[image: The chair starts to rip a hole,you can see a bit of chair's back]

[image: The hole got bigger and the cloth just fall]

Comment: Try increasing the collision quality in *Physics > Cloth Collision*.

Answer (score 3):

You could try a couple of things:

- Increase the "Distance" value under *Physics > Cloth Collision*
- Increase the Structural Stiffness of the Cloth
- Increase the Repulsion Force
- Increase the Repulsion Distance
- Increase the Collision Quality under *Physics > Cloth Collision*

Answer (score 1):

in physics turn "Off" collision for the cloth.  Collision just needs to be on the object it collides.